# Django/Python - Serial line concurrency

Tags: python, django, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I'm currently working on gateway with an embedded Linux and a Webserver. The goal of the gateway is to retrieve data from electrical devices through a RS485/Modbus line, and to display them on a server.

I'm using Nginx and Django, and the web front-end is delivered by "static" files. Repeatedly, a Javascript script file makes AJAX calls that send CGI requests to Nginx. These CGI requests are answered with JSON responses thanks to Django. The responses are mostly data that as been read on the appropriate Modbus device.

The exact path is the following :
Randomly timed CGI call -> urls.py -> ModbusCGI.py (import an other script ModbusComm.py)-> ModbusComm.py create a Modbus client and instantly try to read with it.

Next to that, I wanted to implement a Datalogger, to store data in a DB at regular intervals. I made a script that also import the ModbusComm.py script, but it doesn't work : sometime multiple Modbus frames are sent at the same time (datalogger and cgi scripts call the same function in ModbusComm.py "files" at the same time) which results in an error.

I'm sure this problem would also occur if there are a lot of users on the server (CGI requests sent at the same time). Or not ? (queue system already managed for CGI requests? I'm a bit lost)

So my goal would be to make a queue system that could handle calls from several python scripts => make them wait while it's not their turn => call a function with the right arguments when it's their turn (actually using the modbus line), and send back the response to the python script so it can generate the JSON response.

I really don't know how to achieve that, and I'm sure there are better way to do this.

If I'm not clear enough, don't hesitate to make me aware of it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I had to allow multiple processes to read some Modbus (and not only Modbus) data through a serial port. I ended up with a standalone process (“serial port server”) that exclusively works with a serial port. All other processes work with that port through that standalone process via some inter processes communication mechanism (we used Unix sockets).

This way when an application wants to read a Modbus register it connects to the “serial port server”, sends its request and receives the response. All the actual serial port communication is done by the “serial port server” in sequential way to ensure consistency.

Comment: I'm very (very) late. But I'd day thanks you: I didn't see your response but ultimately I also used a python socket (with a concurrency of 1 client at a time). This seems to be the right solution; it worked well for me.